# How can you embed multiple SVG images in a print layout using a scripted procedure?

Tags: ruby, svg

I currently have a script that produces a large amount of 3.5-inch-square SVG images.  What I need is to be able to put these SVGs in a layout which can be easily and accurately printed.

I have tried using an HTML template, but HTML/CSS does not have sufficiently robust printing support.

What document layout language is most appropriate for handling SVG images, and how could this be implemented in a scripting language?

I use Ruby to generate my SVGs, and although preferable, it is not required that Ruby also be the language used to generate the print layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest compiling all SVGs to a larger SVG, placing everything where you want it, and convert that to PDF using one of multiple options:

- Using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) on the command line, like
   
  `inkscape -f in.svg -A out.pdf`
- Using [Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)
  `java -jar batik-rasterizer.jar -m application/pdf -d out.pdf in.svg`
- Using [librsvg](https://live.gnome.org/LibRsvg), like
  `rsvg-convert -f pdf -o out.pdf in.svg`
  (Probably the most lightweight option)

You might also be able to use the [rsvg2 Ruby gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rsvg2) with a Cairo PDF surface. Documentation seems scarce or scattered, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I ended up using Batik, because none of the other SVG renderers correctly implemented my CSS attribute selectors.  Batik is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a budget, [Prince](http://www.princexml.com) is what you want. Since you've already tried to use CSS+HTML to get it working, you may have a working solution almost ready. Just generate the HTML, SVG, and CSS (use the [CSS3 paged media extensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) for best control), then pass it off to Prince to generate the PDF. I've used this for several projects, and it works great.

There are free options that work like Prince, notably [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), but they might not respect your paging options as much as Prince.

Otherwise, you might be able to hack something together using [Cairo](http://cairosvg.org), by creating a page-sized SVG image and laying it out, adding links to the multiple external SVG files.

Either of these options will end up generating a PDF, which is the only way to ensure that it will print the same no matter which browser or OS is being used.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Prince looks nifty, but unfortunately I do not have much of a budget.  wkhtmltopdf might have worked, but on the first try, it did not render my layout correctly.  I think that an HTML layout just isn't the right tool for the job.